# Can't use off() to turn off event handlers with an event handler for a dynamic list (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm new to js/jQuery.
I have a list that can be modified and added to within the page defined by:
`<ol id="elementlist"></ol>`

On page load, it is an empty list. List items are appended to it with JQuery.

I want to be able to hover over each element and change the color. I've accomplished this using the `on()` function provided by jQuery:

```
// highlight on mouseover 
$("#elementlist").on("mouseover", "li", function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#f2fdf2");
    });

// restore white background    
$("#elementlist").on("mouseout", "li", function(){ 
        $(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");
    });
```

I also want to be able to double click on an li, highlight it and leave it highlighted. This should also disable changing color when hovering over that element. I can double click and change the color but I can't disable the hovering handlers with the following code:

```
// highlights on double click, but doesn't disable mouseover/mouseout
$("#elementlist").on("dblclick", "li", function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#f2d2d2");
        $(this).off("mouseover", "");
        $(this).off("mouseout", "");
    });
```

I haven't been able to disable just the particular list item that has been clicked ( the other list items should still be able to highlight). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The event is bound to the parent `ol`, using `off()` to the `li`s has no effect because they have no event bound to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use data() or a class to set the highlighted state, and check for that :

```
$("#elementlist").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('highlight')) $(this).css("background-color","#f2fdf2");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('highlight')) $(this).css("background-color","#fff");
    },
    dblclick: function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","#f2d2d2").addClass('highlight');
    }
}, 'li');
```

You could also do most of this with CSS:

```
#elementlist li {background-color : #f2fdf2}
#elementlist li:hover {background-color : #fff}
#elementlist li.highlight, #elementlist li.highlight:hover {background-color : f2d2d2}
```

and just keep the click handler

```
$("#elementlist").on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v52zD/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the css explanation too that makes a lot sense.

Answer (score 1):

The event is bound to the parent `ol`, using `off()` to the `li`s has no effect because they have no event bound to them.

One solution would be to bind the event to the `li`s that do not have a `disabledhover` class. And then add such class on double click.

```
// highlight on mouseover 
$("#elementlist").on("mouseover", "li:not(.disabledhover)", function(){
     $(this).css("background-color","#f2fdf2");
});

// restore white background    
$("#elementlist").on("mouseout", "li:not(.disabledhover)", function(){ 
     $(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");
});

// highlights on double click, but doesn't disable mouseover/mouseout
$("#elementlist").on("dblclick", "li", function(){
     $(this).css("background-color","#f2d2d2");
     $(this).addClass("disabledhover");
});
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/Gf6es/)**.

Comment: @roasted Yep. Many solutions. Personally I'd just use CSS hover and an additional class (or `data()`, like you said). In the answer, though, I tried to suggest what is nearest to the OP's current situation.

Comment: Thanks your explanation of off()'s binding clarified my error.

Answer (score 0):

You listener was on the '#elementList' element, that's why off() didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/HShzg/1/

```
$("li", "#elementlist")
.on("mouseover", function(){
    // highlight on mouseover 
    $(this).css("background-color","#f2fdf2");
})
.on("mouseout", function(){ 
    // restore white background   
    $(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");
})
.on("dblclick", function(){
    // highlights on double click, but doesn't disable mouseover/mouseout
    $(this).css("background-color","#f2d2d2");
    $(this).off();
});
```

PS: 
If your list has a lot of elements, maybe so many listeners wouldn't be a good idea, and you should think a 'flag' way to switch on/off the bindings, like @nnnnnn said.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the handler isn't bound directly to the individual li elements, but of course you can't use `.off()` on the parent element or it wouldn't work for any of the li elements. You can do something like this:

```
$("#elementlist").on("mouseover", "li", function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass("fixedBackground"))
        $(this).css("background-color","#f2fdf2");
});
// restore white background    
$("#elementlist").on("mouseout", "li", function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass("fixedBackground"))
        $(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");
});
$("#elementlist").on("dblclick", "li", function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#f2d2d2")
           .addClass("fixedBackground");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t8c23/

That is, on double-click add a class to the element that indicates its background should not be changed again, and in the mouseover/out handlers test for that class.

Ideally you could define the new class in your stylesheet so that the background colour is set via the class rather than hard-coding the colour value directly in your JS.